# Matrices in MaTeX

Tags: matex

Is it possible to display matrices using MaTeX? I tried:

```
 MaTeX["\\begin{matrix}c\\\\f\\end{matrix}"]
```

but it did not display the matrix.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

V12.1 on windows 10.

It works for me

this option setting is not even needed, works without it, but you could try adding it, may be your latex is different.

```
 SetOptions[MaTeX, "Preamble" -> {"\\usepackage{amsmath}"}];
```

Now

```
 MaTeX["\\begin{pmatrix}
     1 & 2 & 3\\\\
     a & b & c
 \\end{pmatrix}", Magnification -> 2]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
MaTeX["\\begin{matrix}c\\\\f\\end{matrix}", Magnification -> 2]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
MaTeX["\\begin{bmatrix}
 1 & 2 & 3\\\\
 a & b & c
 \\end{bmatrix}", Magnification -> 2]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
MaTeX["\\begin{Bmatrix}
 1 & 2 & 3\\\\
 a & b & c
 \\end{Bmatrix}", Magnification -> 2]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
MaTeX["\\begin{Vmatrix}
 1 & 2 & 3\\\\
 a & b & c
 \\end{Vmatrix}", Magnification -> 2]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
MaTeX["\\begin{vmatrix}
 1 & 2 & 3\\\\
 a & b & c
 \\end{vmatrix}", Magnification -> 2]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Also you can do

```
 (data = Table[i + j, {i, 3}, {j, 4}]) // MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
  MaTeX[TeXForm@data, Magnification -> 2]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Actually, `\usepackage{amsmath}` is already in the default preamble (in `"BasePreamble"`) because the output of `TeXForm` sometimes requires it. This is why the setting is not needed.

Comment: @Szabolcs Thanks, this explains why then it worked without needing `amsmath` explicitly added, since these commands come from this package. Yes, one can not do much math without this package, so having it there by default is a good idea.